# RSS Import Into .net

Tags: asp.net, rss

I'd like to import an RSS feed from WordPress into a .net site, limiting the import to the most current post, not the whole feed. As of now, I have to hide all posts, except the first, via the :first-child pseudo element in my non-public project's stylesheet, which won't work well in the public site (hidden content).

The following is what I have now:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" CssClass="blog-rss">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <h4><a href="<%# XPath("link") %>"><%# XPath("title") %></a></h4>
         <span class="author"><%# XPath("pubDate") %></span><br />
            <%# XPath("description") %>
            <hr />
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>

  <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" Runat="server"
      DataFile="http://blog.domain.com/category/signs/feed/"
      XPath="rss/channel/item">
   </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Any suggestions or modifications to the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the XPath to only get the first item in the feed

```
  <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" Runat="server"
      DataFile="http://blog.domain.com/category/signs/feed/"
      XPath="rss/channel/item[1]">
   </asp:XmlDataSource>
```